# Allow 5k or or 7500 rep users to view delete votes on questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools, privileges, vote-to-delete

Users get to [view close votes at 250 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes), which helps gradually slide them into moderating the community by showing them a little more of what's going on. This is really cool as it lets you get more involved, but at the same time makes you want to get more rep to actually cast close votes yourself.

Could we do the same with delete votes? I'm not at 10k and can't see them or cast them, so I don't know how often they come up or how relevant they are or much about them in general. But IMHO if they are like close votes at all it'd be a cool way to do the same thing that getting 250 rep does with a bigger privilege and help usher people in to make the jump between 3k and 10k.

Thoughts? :D

Answer (score 2):

250 rep only lets you view close votes on your *own* questions, which is only the case because you can also cast close votes on your own questions (the privilege is [very poorly named](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68512/is-the-explanation-of-view-close-votes-misleading/68515#68515)). Just like full close voting at 3k, question delete voting at 10k, and answer delete voting at 20k, you can't see votes until you can cast them

Comment: That would make sense...I take it being able to see the votes before you cast them wouldn't make much sense, I just asked this because I thought that was the case with close-votes.

Comment: Do you think there could be any merit in letting people see the votes before they can cast them?